# Get Video url embedded in web page using WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiwebview, wkwebview

I used `UIWebView` to get the video url embedded in web page using `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification`. Due to memory pressure issue I used `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`, which is far better memory efficient than `UIWebView`. But I did not get a way to fetch the url of embedded video. I am still searching on this issue and found some similar questions in stack overflow, but all questions are unanswered.

Please suggest a method to get the embedded video url in web page using `WKWebView`

Comment: can show me how did you get links from `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification ` I have this issue :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988987/get-video-url-from-avplayer-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 5):

Atlast I found a solution to get the video embedded in the web page using WKWebVIew. We can add javascript code to get the url. The video url will be available only after loading the selected video.

```
[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.querySelector('video').currentSrc;" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        // result will contain the video url
 }];
```

Comment: Its not working for iframe video url. Do you have a solution?

Comment: it is called after video loading so how to get without loading of video and when became to play i wan't to get this url.