# Get video URL from AVPlayer in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to detect URL of current video playing from UIWebView, with this method :

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemBecameCurrent(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name("AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"), object: nil)

        //urlTextField.text = webView.request?.url?.absoluteString

        return true
    }



  func playerItemBecameCurrent(notification:Notification)  {

        let playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem
        if playerItem == nil {
            return
        }
        // Break down the AVPlayerItem to get to the path
        let asset: AVURLAsset? = (playerItem?.asset as? AVURLAsset)
        let url: URL? = asset?.url
        let path: String? = url?.absoluteString
        print(path!)

    }
```

This code works but the video URL doesn't contain any video file extension:
 for example here is YouTube and Vimeo video ULRs :

```
https://r5---sn-ab5l6nzr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&requiressl=yes&clen=27257208&mn=sn-ab5l6nzr&mm=31&mv=m&mt=1499534990&key=yt6&ms=au&source=youtube&ip=107.182.226.163&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&initcwndbps=3565000&id=o-ACG22m-TtwyC8tSG_AHUJk3qOPvhUm1X_-qRjy07pjIx&ei=-hZhWZXcJ_aV8gS2tbCQDg&lmt=1497638262979584&ratebypass=yes&gir=yes&pl=25&expire=1499556698&dur=316.093&signature=94C8ED3E4AF64A7AC9F1B7E226454823B236CA55.C18F5F5D9D314B73EDD01DFC4EA3CEA1621AC6C7&ipbits=0&itag=18&cpn=Wb3RPNfJRcFx5P-x&c=MWEB&cver=1.20170706&ptk=TiTV2010%2Buser&oid=1nI2Jk44kRu4HLE6kGDUrA&ptchn=E2VhHmwp3Y_wZvgz_LJvfg&pltype=content
```

and Vimeo :

```
https://36skyfiregce-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1499539063~acl=%2F222646835%2F%2A~hmac=dc3caeb64501f537e2795ee8e121aed75a7eed9ba4e1b921fe92c757fe06b314/222646835/video/778109097,778109103,778109102,778109101/master.m3u8?f=dash
```

Comment: Would you please stop adding irrelevant tags to your question. Your question is not about a physical iPhone nor is it about the Xcode IDE. Please read the description of a tag before using it. Thanks.

Comment: `.m3u8`  for Vimeo is an well known "format" for videos. You can look it up. For the reste, doesn't it have at least some `<video...>` tags or players one ?

Comment: There is no file extension because UIWebView is playing video from a stream ;), so you can't download it directly.

Comment: @Larme m3u8 is not a video file format, it's a playlist file.

Comment: @Larme , Look I am just need a way to download movie from website like youtube and etc... There are some downloader in app store which when you tap on a video to watch , automatically an alert shows up and you can download video file

Comment: @ninjaproger please read above comment

Comment: @Mc.Lover I guess this app doesn't download a move like a regular file, but it caches stream content and saves it on a disk like a file

Comment: A similar question has been previously asked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765839/ios-swift-cant-retrieve-current-url-loaded-in-uiwebview

Comment: it's not working in WKWebView can you help me see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i want to tell you you're coding is working fine.

### **Mirror Server**

It is because during the uploading, downloading and streaming process google is using a mirror server with domain name `googlevideo.com`.

You accessing the link video while in streaming state. You will get that mirror link only.
`Youtube videos` resided inside this mirror server.

Same like that `Vimeo` is using mirror server `akamaized.net`

Refer the [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32383571/5215474) For clarification

### Decoding The Video Link From Mirror URL

So in this condition what we need to have is unique id of video in youtube and same can be accessed by appending the url `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id_here`

For decoding the unique id from this mirror url is impossible as by [SO Answer](https://superuser.com/a/1052129)

They have added this mirror server concept, is for having some security.

As per youtube T&C.. section 5B here -- http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

> Downloading YouTube content is not in compliance with the YouTube
>   Tearms of Service.

There are some private API like [PSYouTubeExtractor](https://github.com/steipete/PSYouTubeExtractor).

I think you need to have URL of video for downloading purpose.

Comment: Just forget youtube it was just an answer , you download this app : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browser-and-file-manager-for-documents/id979401801?mt=8  
it downloads any kind of video from any website !

Comment: Alamofire will do this for you.. to download anyfiles

Answer (score 0):

You can get MIME type and raw data like this:

```
func playerItemBecameCurrent(notification:Notification)  {
        guard let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem,
            let asset = playerItem.asset as? AVURLAsset else {return}
        let url = asset.url
        var response: URLResponse? = nil
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
        try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returning: &response)
        print(response?.mimeType)
        //not the best way to do it
        //let data = try? Data(contentsOf: asset.url)
    }
```

Then you can choose appropriate extension that matches MIME type. You can get all supported types by calling `AVURLAsset.audiovisualMIMETypes()`

Comment: Can we get video name?